# Timer not working - as3

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, timer, air

I am trying to create a simple timer which will take the user back to the login screen after a period of inactivity(60 seconds). The timer seems to work fine the first time and it navigates the user back to the login screen. However, when I log back in to the application the second time, the timer does not work and the user is not navigated to the login screen after 60 seconds. What am I missing and why does it not work the second time?

```
private var timer:Timer;

override protected function initialize():void
{
    timer = new Timer((1)*60*1000, 1);
    timer.start();
    timer.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, onMouseMove);
    timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, onTimerComplete);
}

private function onMouseMove(event:MouseEvent):void
{
   timer.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, onMouseMove);
   timer.reset();
   timer.start();
}

private function onTimerComplete(event:TimerEvent):void
{
  timer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, onTimerComplete);
  this.owner.showScreen(LOGIN_SCREEN);
  timer.reset();
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I see in the code provided, here is what I imagine the solution would be:

1. Make sure the `initialize` method is called every time the user "logs on"
2. **Add/remove the mouse move listener on `stage` not the timer object**  (this is why it isn't working, mouse move will never fire on a non-display object)
3. Move `timer.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, onMouseMove);` to the `onTimerComplete` method  *instead of the the `onMouseMove` method.*

This way, the mouse move will continue to reset the timer until the timer completes.  When the timer completes, both listeners are removed and the user is "logged out".

When the user logs back in,  you call `initialize` and the listeners are added again.

---

You could try using this instead of the `initialize` method: (assuming that framework removes screens from the stage when the current screen changes)

in you constructor for the class posted:

```
this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, addedToStage);
this.addEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, removedFromStage);
```

And your other methods:

```
private function addedToStage(e:Event):void {
    timer = new Timer((1)*60*1000, 1);
    timer.start();
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, onMouseMove);
    timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, onTimerComplete);
}

private function removedFromStage(e:Event):void {
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, onMouseMove);
    timer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, onTimerComplete);
}

private function onMouseMove(event:MouseEvent):void
{
   timer.reset();
   timer.start();
}

private function onTimerComplete(event:TimerEvent):void
{
   this.owner.showScreen(LOGIN_SCREEN);
   timer.reset();
}
```

Comment: Thank you @LDMS for your reply. I found that the initialize() was not being called every time the user 'logs in'. I am trying to fix that and hopefully this will fix the timer issue. Thank you very much..!

Comment: I am overriding Initialize() method from feathers.controls.screen. For some reason, when I log back in the second time, the initialize() method is not called. Any idea why?

Comment: You'll have to post your code.  Right now I have no idea how and when your `initialize` method gets called.   I'm not familiar with the feathers library, but looking at the documentation I see this "runs once when screen is first added to the stage." - perhaps you could use the `Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE` event to setup your timer/listeners instead of the initilize method

Answer (score -1):

I suspect the problem is that you removed the event listener for the timer, you have to reinitialize the timer, also why are you removing the event listener for mouse move?

Comment: Thank you @simion314 for your reply. I tried running the application without removing the mouse move event & timer event and it still doesn't seem to work.